# iOS custom framework not showing Module option on Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have created a Custom Framework on a separated project. Now, I have included it on other project and I am facing some problems.

In that framework I have created some IBInspectable components. When I try to use them from another project I am not able to see my frameworks name under Module as seen in the following image.

[image]

As you can see, dropdown does not show my module´s name. So, if I compile this the application does not show the component as it should be.

But, if I write the name of the component there as seen in the following screenshot, when I compile the component is shown correctly.

[image]

Any idea of how to make my project to show this custom framework under dropdown module menu?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you including the framework in this project? Have you added the binary?

Comment: I have compiled it as a universal framework. So, I have added the .framework under embedded binaries

Comment: Grasping at straws here, but did you also add it to (1) Linked frameworks and libraries and (2) added it as a Target Membership of the project? I think you've done the right stuff, thus my last thoughts.

Comment: Yep, everything is set up, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: How did you resolved it?